# Is it possible to define an example in Doxygen inside the comment?

Tags: comments, doxygen

It looks like the only way to define an example in doxygen is to put it in a separate file. The documentation can be found [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdexample).

Is it possible to define the example directly inside the doxygen comment?

Comment: I think that for your request you can put the code directly in e.g. a code or verbatim block. Also you can use the snippet command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `\code` tag works good for me:

```
<b>Example</b>
\code{.c}
...
\endcode
```